# Scan page and find missing header tags

Tags: javascript, java, accessibility, html-heading

We're implementing accessibility on our site. As the content on the site is authorable, one of the requirements asked by the client was to be informed if the header tags are skipped on a page. For eg. if h3 tag is used after h1 instead of h2. Please let me know if this can done in Javascript/Java preferably.

Comment: What do you mean "Java"? Java in the browser has been removed from almost every browser.

Answer (score 1):

To check for skipped heading levels you need to iterate through the headings on a page and check that they either:

- stay the same (same level)
- decrease (back up one or more levels)
- increase (by only one).

If none of the above are true then you have an error.

The below snippet will check for all of these and then return an array of items for you to debug.

The fields returned are:

- **previousHeadingLevel**: the previous **correct** heading level so you can check nesting (useful to see if the error is actually that this heading level is incorrect and should be one level lower!),
- **seenHeadingLevel**: the heading level we saw,
- **expectedHeadingLevel**: the heading level we were expecting to see,
- **seenHeadingText**: the text of the heading that has skipped a heading level so you can find it,
- **previousHeadingText**: the text of the previous heading so you can find it easily on the page.

### Usage

To use the following snippet you can call it with `checkheadings()` to check the entire document.

Alternatively you can call it while passing in a valid `querySelector` variable such as `.myClass` to only check within a particular element (useful for complex documents).

**Please note:** As it is *technically* valid to have more than one `<h1>` in a document this does not check for that, however it is worth noting that it is considered a good practice to only have one `<h1>` per page.

### Code Example

```js
function getHeadingLevel(heading) {
    return parseInt(heading.tagName[1]);
}

function createError(expectedHeadingLevel, previousHeadingLevel, previousHeadingText, currentHeadingLevel, currentHeadingText){
  var err = {};
  err.previousHeadingLevel = (previousHeadingLevel == 0) ? "no previous headings" : previousHeadingLevel;
  err.seenHeadingLevel = currentHeadingLevel;
  err.expectedHeadingLevel = expectedHeadingLevel;
  err.seenHeadingText = currentHeadingText;
  err.previousHeadingText = previousHeadingText;
  
  return err;
}


function checkheadings(container) {
    container = container || 'body';
    var cont = document.querySelector(container);
    var headings = cont.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");
    var errors = [];
    var previousHeadingLevel = 0;
    var previousHeadingText = "Document Start - no headings yet";
    
    if (headings.length < 1) {
        errors.push("no headings detected");
        return errors;
    }

    for (x = 0; x < headings.length; x++) {
        var currentHeadingLevel = getHeadingLevel(headings[x]);
        var currentHeadingText = headings[x].textContent;
        var expectedHeadingLevel = previousHeadingLevel + 1;
        if (currentHeadingLevel > expectedHeadingLevel) {
            //errors.push("H" + expectedLevel + " skipped. Previous correct heading was H" + previousHeadingLevel + " containing text:" + previousHeadingText + ". Unexpected H" + currentHeadingLevel + " text: " + currentHeadingText);
            
            errors.push(createError(expectedHeadingLevel, previousHeadingLevel, previousHeadingText, currentHeadingLevel, currentHeadingText));
            
            continue;
        }

        previousHeadingLevel = currentHeadingLevel;
        previousHeadingText = currentHeadingText;
    }


    return errors;
}

console.log("1 error", checkheadings('.test1'));
console.log("3 errors", checkheadings('.test2'));
console.log("no errors", checkheadings('.test3'));
console.log("entire document", checkheadings());
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <h1>h1-1</h1>
  <h2>h2-1</h2>
  <h4>h4-1 - skipped</h4>
  <h3>h3-1</h3>
  <h2>h2-2</h2>
  <h3>h3-2</h3>
  <h2>h2-2</h2>
  <h2>h2-3</h2>
  <h3>h3-3</h3>
</div>
<div class="test2">
  <h2>h2 - skipped</h2>
  <h1>h1-1</h1>
  <h4>h4-1 - skipped</h4>
  <h3>h3-1 - skipped</h3>
</div>
<div class="test3">
  <h1>h1-1</h1>
  <h2>h2-1</h2>
  <h3>h3-1</h3>
  <h2>h2-2</h2>
  <h3>h3-2</h3>
  <h2>h2-3</h2>
  <h3>h3-3</h3>
  <h4>h4-1</h4>
  <h5>h5-1</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a very nice utility script. Well done! When I tested (in chrome), it kept throwing errors on `cont.querySelectorAll`, but changing `cont` to `document` made everything work. A few thoughts on this: (1) scripting can tell you if levels are skipped, but no algorithm can determine if the correct heading level is being used - that requires human verification, and (2) sectioning elements may possibly change the expected flow, thereby giving false positives. Great answer.

Comment: How strange it threw an error, I only built it in a fiddle so I am guessing it is something to do with the default of `document.querySelector('body');` (or did you call it with a selector?) - I only built it that way for the demo (so I could run 3 scenarios) and for the ability to test sections, I will see if I can fix that. Great points on the 2 bits of human verification needed! Now I am having a head scratch on whether I can account for sectioning elements too 

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6")` and then analyze the resulting node list.

I am not sure how your desired output looks like. This code snippet will return an array with the numbers of all  that are skipped.
Also it only expects one h1, h2, ... respectively.

```js
const headings = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6")

const getHeadingNumber = (heading) => parseInt(heading.tagName[1])

let lastHeadingNumber;
const skippedHeadings = []
for (let heading of headings) {
  if(!lastHeadingNumber) {
    lastHeadingNumber = getHeadingNumber(heading)
    continue;
  }
  
  const currentHeadingNumber = getHeadingNumber(heading)
  const expectedHeadingNumber = lastHeadingNumber + 1
  
  if(expectedHeadingNumber !== currentHeadingNumber) {
    skippedHeadings.push(expectedHeadingNumber)
  }
  
  lastHeadingNumber = currentHeadingNumber;
}
console.log(skippedHeadings)
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<h3></h3>
<h5></h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a java basic web crawler https://mkyong.com/java/jsoup-basic-web-crawler-example/ and using Jsoup you can do the parsing

```
// Group of all h-Tags
Elements hTags = doc.select("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");

// Group of all h1-Tags
Elements h1Tags = hTags.select("h1");
// Group of all h2-Tags
Elements h2Tags = hTags.select("h2");
// ... etc.
```

Ensure whehter we have multiple H1 that is also problemtaic in SEO